# The last query of the 15 records in the table, but includes data in related tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to put together three different tables that will work together.
To do this I used the following code:

```
SELECT
    u.username,
    v.name,
    v.thumbnail,
    v.type,
    v.quality,
    v.title_id,
    v.updated_at,
    v.id,
    n.views,
    n.id
FROM
    videos v
        JOIN
    users u ON v.user_id = u.id
        JOIN
    titles n ON n.views = v.title_id
ORDER BY v.id DESC
LIMIT 15
```

So what I'm actually doing is plugging in who uploaded the episode, where he uploaded the episode, and I now want to add the amount of views they did to the episode.

Attached are screenshots of the SQL

[image]
This is the table named users

[image]
This is the table named titles From here I just want the views

[image]
This is the table called videos

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You join tables linking IDs: primary key with foreign key. In your sql you linked number of views with foreign key, which is not correct. However next time please provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of screenshots.

```
SELECT
    u.username,
    v.name,
    v.thumbnail,
    v.type,
    v.quality,
    v.title_id,
    v.updated_at,
    v.id,
    n.views,
    n.id
FROM
    videos v
        JOIN
    users u ON v.user_id = u.id
        JOIN
    titles n ON n.id = v.title_id
ORDER BY v.id DESC
LIMIT 15
```